# Retrieve text from server in Android

Tags: android

I have the following code in java ( android):

```
            String image = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pic_image",image));
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.image); 
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new    HttpPost("http://www.carprotectionsystem.webuda.com/image.php");         

    try {   
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response  = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if(entity !=null)
        {
        InputStream instream=entity.getContent();
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(convertStreamToString(instream));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            image =jsonResponse.getString("pic_image");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } 
        tv1.setText(image);
        }
                     }   
              } 
            catch (Exception e) 
                    {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }    }
```

and the php script gives me in the browser this response:`{"pic_image":"a"}`

I want to display "a" in a textview in android but I am getting this error:
`org.json.JSONexception : value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject` 
Any Help ?

Comment: please post your whole response of json.

Comment: Something is really wrong with the HTML output. The HTML is definately not valid, also you _only_ want to return JSON, not html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the response of the server (in your browser, right click -> show source). You will see that it send you html content and not JSON content.
Here is what you receive :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>{"pic_image":"a"}</body>
</html>
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

You cant't parse this as a JSONObject.

Comment: Good catch :) Something is really wrong server side to output this mangled HTML.

Answer (score -1):

```
Use this method to get string from response entity:

    public String convertStreamToString(final InputStream instream) throws IOException, ParseException {

        if (instream == null) {
            return "";
        }

        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, "utf-8"));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

        } finally {
            instream.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

Comment: This won't help. It first needs to output proper JSON serverside.